# How to design the bit-bucket pipeline for deployement the code of one repo to multiple servers using php?

Tags: php, bitbucket-pipelines, ftp-server

I want to design the bit-bucket pipeline using php for deployement of code from one repo to multiple server locations. Following code is working to deploy the code to repo but I want to update the same code to multiple sever too.

```
# Pipeline -- bitbucket-pipelines.yml

image: php:7.1.29

pipelines:
  custom: # Pipelines that can only be triggered manually
    master:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to production
          deployment: production
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - git ftp push --user $FTP_username --passwd $FTP_password server_address
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, the community is supposed to help you with difficulties over your code, maybe your question does not fit in this group without any research or code from you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file in your repository.

Create a deployment step, specify a `script` for deployment (e.g. via FTP or SCP). 
You can split multiple servers into different steps or deploy to all servers from a single step.

See [BitBucket Pipelines docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered dockerizing the app? Let's say you have the image pushed to docker hub then you can configure the different servers to pull the latest images. You can achieve this using [watchtower](https://containrrr.github.io/watchtower/usage-overview/).